# Power & Sleep in Windows 10 doesn't match Power Plan settings

Tags: windows-10, sleep, power, power-management, default-settings

When in the "Power & Sleep" settings in Windows (left), the "Screen off and sleep settings" from the control panel (right) don't match those values:

[image]

Question 1:  Which one is going to override which?

Question 2:  Why wouldn't they make it so which ever setting overrides the other, the other setting updates to that value?

Comment: There’s no overriding. These settings are the same. Note that these settings pages do not auto-refresh when you change settings elsewhere. // There is no 4 minutes option on the left view.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually "comparing" 3 different input fields "at the same time":

1. the power option in the "control panel" (top right)
2. the advanced power option in the "control panel" (lower right)
3. the power option in the "settings" (left)

If you close everything (or more specific the one(s) you **didn't** do the change in) and open it again you'll see the value has been updated and they will be all the same.

There will be no mismatch if you "open the other" after you make the change.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case. I set my desired setting 'advanced power options, or in the control panel, save it, yet the times are different in the Power & Sleep options.

Comment: @moobot What build of Windows 10 are you using? Can you make a step by step description so I can replicate the problem?